# Respawning 2 player objects at the same time in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am creating an arena style battle game in Unity and I am having a problem with respawning players.  Here's how it works right now.

When a player is killed it is put into a list of killed players to be respawned and it's player object is destroyed. The game then loops thru the list of killed players and selects a random available spawn point then respawns the player there. An available spawn point is any spawn point that is not triggered by a player being inside it's spawn area.

The problem comes when 2 players die at the same time, or at least extremely close to the same time and the randomly selected spawn point ends up to be the same because it didn't have enough time to process as triggered.  When this happens all of unity crashes and I have to restart it completely.

I assume that in order to fix this, I need to keep Unity from spawning them at the same time, but I thought that would be fixed by looping thru the list.  How should I actually go about spawning 2 players that die at the same time more safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem and I'm able to keep it with random spawn points.  The problem didn't apparently have to do with 2 players dying at the same time so much as it had to do with a player dying while on a spawnpoint. When this happens it would not run the OnTriggerLeave() method and therefore would not count as an available spawnpoint even tho nothing was there.

I fixed it by having each spawnpoint hold a list of all the game objects that were triggering it which would change as players entered and exited the space.  Then when a player was killed, it would check each spawnpoint's list to see if it contained the player's game object.  If it found a match then I untrigger the spawnpoint and it appears as available.

A better approach to this which I am going to do instead is to check the list to see if there are any gameobjects in the spawnpoint's list and it should only be available if there are none. Because the current way doesn't account for other objects also triggering the point.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic queue example the same thing happens in multi threaded applications. Two things you can do here:

1. Diversion of concern
2. Remove the conflict from beginning

In the first method you create an script outside of your player script for example in the arena it self and create a method there to select the next spawning point. This can be ordinal instead of random and each player upon death asks the script to select the next spawning point for it and no conflict over one point.

In the second method each player will have it's own spawning point for example an offset from the spawning points defined in the arena. For example player 1 will have offset zero and spawn right on spawning point then player two will have offset 1 which will spawn 1 unit off of the spawning point.

I prefer the first method if the number of players are limited. If you have many players then the queue might be a bother.

Hope it helps :)